# Android map application force closing on device

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maps

I'm trying to learn building an Android Google Map application. I get a force close when trying to run the app on my Samsung device. Here's the code:
Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.yomap"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<permission android:name="com.example.yomap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"       android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.yomap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.yomap.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"        />


<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.anshole.yomap.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API.KEY"
    android:value="<my api key value here>" />
</application>
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and MainActivity.java

```
package com.anshole.yomap;

import com.example.yomap.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Device I'm trying to run this on has Android 2.3.6. What could be the cause behind force close? Pardon me if this is too nooby question.

Comment: can you see the logcat error post that logcat error trace

Comment: [pic of logcat post](http://oi41.tinypic.com/2qjixea.jpg) (I'm new to this.)

Comment: http://twntee.tumblr.com/post/59576020346/the-maps-api-adding-a-map-to-your-android-project go through this post, double check you have all requirements, in your case you are missing the api key, see the post to how to get an api key.

Comment: @twntee mate I do have key, I edited it out while posting the code here. [here's the screenshot of activated key, which I've used in my code as well](http://oi39.tinypic.com/hx6r9l.jpg)

Comment: kindly run the app again, and show the logcat ..

Comment: [Here's the logcat](http://txtup.co/CVOev)

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
   <uses-permission android:name="com.example.yomap.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

To

```
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: Still gives the error. (Application YoMap has stopped unexpectedly.) thanks for the reply.

Comment: Have you reference the google play services library project in your android map project?

Comment: @anshole i guess you have not referenced google play services library project in your map project. Alos paste your stack trace here by exporting it to a text file from your ide. screen shots won't help

Comment: @anshole id you read the logcat. it says check your  key in manifest. You should use the key that you get from the google api console. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Comment: I have used the API key, from API console/

Comment: @anshole then use the same here  `android:value="<my api key value here>"`. then you won't see the error that you posted in logcat

Comment: [its legitimate key, as far as I understand.](http://oi39.tinypic.com/hx6r9l.jpg) is there anything wrong here?

Comment: @anshole it should look like  `android:value="AIzaSyAdxSwKhRM6-Ea1aer9avAKEhNdsSOTehyo"/>`. not `android:value="<my api key value here>"`. I hope you have place the key in between quotes

Comment: Yes the key is there in manifest file. see the image in previous reply, it has screenshot of activated key from code.google.com and same key that I pasted in manifest file..

Comment: If you followed all the steps in the docs it should work. by the way i can't see that image. its too tiny not clearly visible

Comment: click on the image to see larger view, or right click open in new tab to see full size view. I did follow all steps, and key is right as well(as far as i understand)..

Comment: As far as i understand if you follow the steps in the doc it will work. If the key is right you should not see API key not found in your logcat. from the code you have posted this all i can help

Answer (score 0):

Either you haven't link your project to goolge_play_services_lib library project, or you forgot to activate google map v2 service at Google api console.

Try it may be solve your problem.

Comment: Have done both mate. still the error. Posted screenshot of key as well logcat error text file.

Comment: have you added android support v4 or v13 library into your code?

Comment: yup. did that as well. I re-did the project, with basically error free copied code and tried to run it on two different android devices (2.3 and 4.1), both gave errors.